# How can i get some rotated square-like coordinates from a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, 2d, coordinates

I have a 2D array. The initial point is the red one in the center.
On each step i need to get the coordinates of the blue dots, then the green dots, after that the red ones an finally the gray ones (depending on the number of steps given as parameter... in this case...4).

I need to make a method that gets the coordinates. it should look something like this

```
void setDilation(int x, int y, int level) {
    int score = 0;

    if(level== 0)
        return;
    if(x<0 || x==arraySize)
        return;
    if(y<0 || y==arraySize)
        return;

    if(myArray[x-1][y] >= 0)
        score++;
    else
        score --;
    if(myArray[x+1][y] >= 0)
        score++;
    else
        score --;
    if(myArray[x][y-1] >= 0)
        score++;
    else
        score --;
    if(myArray[x][y+1] >= 0)
        score++;
    else
        score --;
    if (score<0) 
        score = 0;
    }
    myArray[x][y] = score;

    setDilation(x-1, y ,level-1);
    setDilation(x+1, y ,level-1);
    setDilation( x ,y-1,level-1);
    setDilation( x ,y+1,level-1);
}
```

Picture:

[image: Here is the picture]

The code sort of does the work, but it returns to a visited coordinate and increase its score again and also I can't control the way the array is explored.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! The link you've provided to the example is broken. Also, please post what you've tried and someone will certainly help out. Take a look at the help section on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please update your post accordingly. :)

Comment: Your `setDilation` method recursive call is missing the `color` parameter.

Comment: Done. I removed it as a parameter to keep the method simple and I forgot to erase it from the list of parameters. I edited it.